# Where we can set property for product is salable or not

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to know where we can set property 'is_salable' for products.

I have checked for all attributes if there any attribute for that but not found any.

Then Where we can set this property to the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot set an is_salable attribute to the product.

After the product is loaded it is already set on the model but it is not an attribute and is not a column in the product flat table.

The method is_salable physically exists but it only checks if the product has enabled status and salable check should not be skipped. Then the is_salable property of the product object is returned.

It is in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped::isSalable().` -for simple products.
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped::isSalable() - for grouped products
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::isSalable() - for configurable products
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::isSalable() - for the rest of product types

This method checks if the product is enabled. If not then false is returned. If it's enabled, then it checks if it has a property is_salable that can be set by one of your observers.